# LibGdx Actions are poolable... How do I check the active size of the pool and other pool parameters?

Tags: libgdx, action, pool

I create a pool of MoveToAction.. LibGdx actions are already implementing poolable interface..

Whenever an item is selected I move it slightly raise up (along Y axis)

Whenever an item is unselected, I simply drop it back to its original position...

Both times I use MoveToAction (libGdx)   I assume after action is over, the action object will be automatically reset and returned to pool. I just wanted to check the status of the pool, everytime I obtain poolMoveAction.obtain();  But there is no way of doing it.. How do I know for sure, the pool is successfully managed...

I create a pool of MoveToAction..

```
Pool<MoveToAction> poolMoveAction = new Pool<MoveToAction>(6,60) { 
      @Override protected MoveToAction newObject() { 
         return new MoveToAction(); 
     }
 };
```

whenever an item is selected... I raise it along Y axis..

```
     MoveToAction move = poolMoveAction.obtain();
     move.setPosition(baseX,baseY+getHeight()*0.1f);
     move.setDuration(0.2f);
     addAction(move);
```

Whenever an item is unselected, I simply drop it back to its original position...

```
    MoveToAction move = poolMoveAction.obtain(); 
    move.setPosition(baseX,baseY);
    move.setDuration(0.15f);
    addAction(move);
```

I assume after action is over, the action object will be automatically reset and returned to pool. I just wanted to check the status of the pool, everytime I obtain poolMoveAction.obtain();  But there is no way of doing it.. How do I know for sure, the pool is successfully managed...

Answer (score 1):

You can check size of pool by calling `pool.getFree()`. The other thing you can check is `pool.peak`, which is variable that contains highest size of the pool.

Source code of `Pool` class is available here on official libGDX Github: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.java

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I was looking for......  I was looking at the sourcecode but the name getFree() eluded me..  Pool stores only free objects.. which makes sense.. but I was thinking it will be keeping the used ones as well in the list with a flag or something....